# Скриншот Яндекс карт/Yandex Maps screenshot

Tags: swift, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Имеется `view` с некоторыми элементами (включая `YMKMapView`). Нужно сделать скриншот экрана.

Использую следущий код

```
  func renderImage(from view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)
    return image
  }
```

Изображение успешно сохраняется в галерею, но вместо фрагмента карты **белый фон**.

Какой результат должен быть и какой на самом деле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще возможность сделать скриншот в МапКите реализована только для Андроид - MapView.getScreenshot(). Для ios подобного метода нет.
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/full/com/yandex/mapkit/mapview/MapView.html?lang=ru#_51